# Fog directory appends local system path with amazon url when i try to give dynamic fog directory

Tags: amazon-s3, paperclip, proc, fog

I am using FOG with Paperclip. I added the following code to give dynamic directory name.

```
fog_directory: proc { |file| file.instance.repo.name }
```

It creates the fog directory correctly but when i try to get url it added the local system path with amazon url.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/%23%3CProc:0x4ae8f3bb@/home/apple/projects/project.name/config/initializers/paperclip.rb:8%3E/abc.jpg

Comment: Can you share full paperclip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way by overriding the Paperclip module.

```
module Paperclip
    module Storage
        module Fog
            def host_name_for_directory
                if directory_name.to_s =~ Fog::AWS_BUCKET_SUBDOMAIN_RESTRICTON_REGEX
                "#{directory_name}.s3.amazonaws.com"
                else
                "s3.amazonaws.com/#{directory_name}"
                end
            end 

            def directory
                @directory ||= connection.directories.new(key: directory_name)
            end

            def directory_name
        if @options[:fog_directory].respond_to?(:call)
            @options[:fog_directory].call(self)
        else
            @options[:fog_directory]
        end
          end
        end
    end
end
```